# Not able to find tabletogrid function inJQ grid version 5.0.2

Tags: jqgrid

We are currently using JQ grid version 4.1.2 in our application, however we are upgrading JQ grid version from 4.1.2 to 5.0.2 version, we are not able to find tabletogrid function in version 5.0.2. Can anyone help us any alternative tabletogrid function in JQ grid version 5.0.2.

Comment: You can try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.0 instead of commercial version [Guriddo jqGrid JS](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Free jqGrid has `tableToGrid` definitively. You try it by changing URLs to jqGrid files to URLs from CDN (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). I develop free jqGrid fork and try to hold maximal compatibility to the old versions.